# A question on symmetric states of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Suppose two distinct states $i,j$ satisfy
\begin{align*}
\mathbb {P}\left(\tau_{j}<\tau_{i}\vert X_{0}=i\right)=\mathbb {P}\left(\tau_{i}<\tau_{j}\vert X_{0}=j\right),
\end{align*}
where $\tau_{k}:=\inf \left\{n\geq 1:X_{n}=k\right\}$. Show that, if $X_{0}=i$, the expected number of visits to $j$ prior to re-visiting $i$ is one. Suppose $N$ is the number of visits to $j$ before visiting to $i$ and $\theta=\mathbb {P}\left(\tau_{j}<\tau_{i}\vert X_{0}=i\right)=\mathbb {P}\left(\tau_{i}<\tau_{j}\vert X_{0}=j\right)$. When I looked at the solution, I don't quite understand why we have the following derivation:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb {P}(N\geq k\vert X_{0}=i)=\theta (1-\theta)^{k-1} \quad \text{for $k\geq 1$}\Longrightarrow \mathbb {E}(N\vert X_{0}=i)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\theta (1-\theta)^{k-1}=1
\end{align*}
Since I know that in fact
\begin{align*}
\mathbb {P}(N= k\vert X_{0}=i)=\theta (1-\theta)^{k-1}\theta \quad \text{for $k\geq 1$}
\end{align*}
so what's wrong with the following formula? Thanks a lot!
\begin{align*}
\mathbb {E}(N\vert X_{0}=i)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\cdot\theta (1-\theta)^{k-1}\theta
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong actually: note that
$$
\mathbb {P}(N\geq k\vert X_{0}=i)=\sum_{j=k}^\infty \mathbb {P}(N=j\vert X_{0}=i)=\theta^2\sum_{j=k}^\infty (1-\theta)^{j-1}=\theta^2(1-\theta)^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty (1-\theta)^{j}=\theta (1-\theta)^{k-1}.
$$
You can recover the result from the last equality in your post by writing
$$
\mathbb {E}(N\vert X_{0}=i)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\cdot\theta (1-\theta)^{k-1}\theta=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^k  \theta (1-\theta)^{k-1}\theta$$
and switch the sums over $j$ and $k$. This gives
$$
\mathbb {E}(N\vert X_{0}=i)=\theta^2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=j}^\infty (1-\theta)^{k-1}=\theta^2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-\theta)^{k+j-1}=\theta^2\sum_{j=1}^\infty (1-\theta)^{j-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-\theta)^k
$$
and the last two series are both equal to $1/\theta$.

Comment: Could you derive the value $1$ based on this equation? The value I calculated is $k\theta \neq 1$. Thanks.

Comment: @Jiexiong687691 I have added details.

Comment: When you switch the two series, why $j=1\to k$ becomes $j=1\to\infty$?

Comment: We write the double sum as $\sum_{k,j\geq 1}\mathbf{1}_{\{j\leq k\}}c_{k,j}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k\geq 1}\mathbf{1}_{\{j\leq k\}}c_{k,j}$.